# Не могу воссоздать запрос к API используя Python requests

Tags: python, requests, cloudflare

Меня интересовал ввод промокода https://store.standoff2.com.
При вводе промокода отправляется POST запрос на https://store.standoff2.com/api/v1/coupon с данными в JSON формате: {'uid': 'player_id', 'coupon': 'coupon'}.

Но когда я пытаюсь повторить этот запрос через Python Requests, то вместо нормального ответа получаю капчу.

Пробовал библиотеку cloudscraper, но она не помогла, также пробовал подставить headers и cookies из браузера в requests.Session, но это было тоже безрезультатно.

Как мне обойти эту капчу, не использую selenium?

Я посмотрел, и нашел строку, которая отправляет запрос
https://store.standoff2.com/static/js/main.76a9dd9a.chunk.js, строка 532.

Так как я сам плохо разбираюсь в JavaScript, я буду очень благодарен, если кто нибудь найдет нужные строки в этом коде для отправки запроса и напишет пример скрипта на Python :)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)